# wget spider returns all URLs twice -- where is the bug?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, wget

I was looking for a script to create a URL list for a sitemap and found this one:

```
wget --spider --force-html -r -l1 http://sld.tld 2>&1 \
  | grep '^--' | awk '{ print $3 }' \
  | grep -v '\.\(css\|js\|png\|gif\|jpg\|ico\|txt\)$' \
  > urllist.txt
```

The result is:

```
http://sld.tld/
http://sld.tld/
http://sld.tld/home.html
http://sld.tld/home.html
http://sld.tld/news.html
http://sld.tld/news.html
...
```

Every URL entry is saved twice. How should the script be changed to fix this?

Comment: Take out each part of your pipeline, starting at the end, until you debug it.

Comment: The part, after that the entries get duplicated, is `| grep '^--'`. It filters the content and I cannot just remove it. But I don't know, how to change this part, in order to avoid this side effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the output of wget when you use the `--spider` flag, it'll look something like:

```
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2013-04-12 22:01:03--  http://www.google.com/intl/en/about/products/
Connecting to www.google.com|173.194.75.103|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Remote file exists and could contain links to other resources -- retrieving.

--2013-04-12 22:01:03--  http://www.google.com/intl/en/about/products/
Reusing existing connection to www.google.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
```

It checks if the link is there (thus prints out a `--`), then it has to download it to look for additional links (thus the second `--`). This is why it shows up (at least twice) when you use `--spider`.

Compare that to without `--spider`:

```
Location: http://www.google.com/intl/en/about/products/ [following]
--2013-04-12 22:00:49--  http://www.google.com/intl/en/about/products/
Reusing existing connection to www.google.com:80.
```

So you only get one line that starts with `--`.

You can remove the `--spider` flag but you could still get duplicates. If you really don't want any duplicates, add a `| sort | uniq` to your command:

```
wget --spider --force-html -r -l1 http://sld.tld 2>&1 \
  | grep '^--' | awk '{ print $3 }' \
  | grep -v '\.\(css\|js\|png\|gif\|jpg\|ico\|txt\)$' \
  | sort | uniq > urllist.txt
```

Comment: I do need the `--spider` flag, since I don't want to store the website content. But thank you very much for `| sort | uniq` -- it works perfectly!

Comment: Is there any way on the server to determine which request is the "check" versus the "download"?  You can filter it from the WGET client results, but it still results in doubled requests on the web server.  (UPDATE:  Check the CGI.Request_Method... the check is HEAD & the download is GET.)